# Mi aplicación (Radio) se detuvo : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Necesito una mano por que tengo un error en ejecución del proyecto de Radio.Yo estuve buscando información y sospecho que el problema está en el Android Manifest que indexo aquí mismo.Pero la verdad todavía soy nuevo en Android.

Android Manifest :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eliseo.radio">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Nosotros" />
        <activity android:name=".Multimedia"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Código Java:

```
package com.example.eliseo.radio;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.rtp.AudioStream; 
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


import java.io.IOException;

import static com.example.eliseo.radio.R.id.play;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton btnPlay;

ImageButton btnRec;
ImageButton btnStp;
ImageButton btnsal;
Button btnMul;
Button btnRa;
Button btnNos;

MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
String stream="http://streams.calmradio.com/api/29/128/stream/;";
boolean prepared,started=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPlay=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
    btnRec=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.reconectar);
    btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.parar);
    btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.salir);
    btnMul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.multimedia);
    btnRa=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio);
    btnNos=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nosotros);

    final Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Esperando respúesta del Servidor...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
    btnRec.setEnabled(false);
    btnStp.setEnabled(false);

    mediaplayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

  //botones Radio
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (started){
                started=false;
                mediaplayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pausa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }else{
                started=true;
                mediaplayer.start();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

    btnStp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
            btnStp.setEnabled(false);
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    btnRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            Intent Recargar=getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(Recargar);
        }
    });

    //Botones Navegacion
    btnsal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.release();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    btnNos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Nosotros=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Nosotros.class);
            startActivity(Nosotros);

        }
    });

    btnMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Multimedia=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Multimedia.class);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });



}

 class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{


    protected Boolean doInBackground(String...String){
        try{
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(String[0]);
            mediaplayer.prepare();
            prepared=true;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){

        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mediaplayer.start();

    }

}
```

}

Contenido del LogCat

> 09-07 17:14:01.723 4243-4243/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   09-07 17:14:01.878 4243-4243/com.example.eliseo.radio W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.eliseo.radio-2/lib/arm
>   09-07 17:14:01.890 4243-4243/com.example.eliseo.radio I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   09-07 17:14:02.150 4243-4243/com.example.eliseo.radio D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   09-07 17:14:02.151 4243-4243/com.example.eliseo.radio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.eliseo.radio, PID: 4243
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eliseo.radio/com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
>   09-07 17:14:02.160 4243-4256/com.example.eliseo.radio I/MediaHTTPConnection: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
>   09-07 17:14:02.163 4243-4256/com.example.eliseo.radio D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>   09-07 17:14:05.222 4243-4295/com.example.eliseo.radio D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué error arroja? ¿Sólo se detiene y ya? en la cadena String stream="http://streams.calmradio.com/api/29/128/stream/;" veo que al final hay un punto y coma (;) puede que ahí haya algún problema.

Comment: Simplemente se detiene ,lo estoy probando en un dispositivo físico inicia la aplicación y simplemente sale un error de "Radio se detuvo " .El Striing  es la dirección de la radio,puedes inclusive ponerla en tu navegador .Antes de instanciar los botones con sus acciones y clases funcionaba la radio así que no creo que ahí se encuentre el error.Gracias

Comment: Podrías desistalarla, borrar caché y volverla a instalar y ejecutar. No arroja ninguna excepción, ¿cierto? Puede ser la memoria.

Comment: Si deseas desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es esencial, de otra forma pueden existir infinidad de razones para que se cierre la aplicación.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de tu layout activity_main ? gracias

Comment: Podrias por favor colocar lo que dice el logcat cuando se detiene la aplicacion

Comment: Hola ,muchas gracias por responder.Contestando a los comentarios:

@Fernando Carraro probe desinstalar ,borre el cache y renitente pero no funciono y sin arrojar ninguna exepcion

Comment: @Jorgesys♦ Muchas gracias por el consejo ,intentare orientar mi aprendizaje en el uso del LogCat

Comment: @GastónSaillén Si no me equivoco creo que es el que tengo puesto en la pregunta ,igual lo colocare completo con las librerías incluidas por si acaso

Comment: @KenjiKawaidaVillegas coloco el contenido actual del logcat ,aunque por lo que estuve averiguando hace  falta un sistema de etiquetas primero creo .Cualquier corrección te agradecería que la comentaras

Comment: buenas @EliseoBaroni asi como te indica el error tienes una referencia nula en tu setOnclickListener, si te fijas definiste `ImageButton btnStp;`
`ImageButton btnsal;`, pero al hacer el findViewById asignates dos veces el mismo image button a btnStp, `btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.parar);`
    `btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.salir);` , cambie el `btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.salir);` por `btnsal=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.salir);` y ya pude ejecutar tu codigo.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, recuerda que debes verificar obtener la referencia y el elemento debe encontrarse en el layout @EliseoBaroni, saludos

Comment: Si, ese fue mi error, muchas gracias .Se que no se puede comentar solo con agradecimientos así que de paso  les pregunto por que aun me quedo un error 
`com.example.eliseo.radio W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.eliseo.radio-1/lib/arm`
Gracias !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas llamando el método `setOnClickListener()` a partir de una instancia con valor null de un botón, esto ocurre por dos situaciones

-Primero,
 debes verificar que todos estos botones :

```
btnPlay=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
btnRec=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.reconectar);
btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.parar);
btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.salir);
btnMul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.multimedia);
btnRa=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio);
btnNos=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nosotros);
```

se encuentren en el layout que carga tu activity mediante  `setContentView()` en este caso el archivo  `activity_main.xml`.

-Segundo, si se encuentra debes obtener la referencia del botón en el .xml.

**Uno de estos botones no se encuentra en el .xml o se encuentra pero no se esta obteniendo la referencia en el .xml**

---

El problema en realidad es `btnsal` ya que declaras la variable pero no buscas su referencia en el xml por lo tanto obtienes una instancia con valor null de este `ImageButton`:

```
ImageButton btnsal;

...
...

    //Botones Navegacion
    btnsal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.release();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```